# Android map fragment with footer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to design a screen with a Google map and a footer. With the footer, i seperated it in a different xml layout file and used '**include**' tag. The problem is the footer overlayed the map. My xml layout files were described bellow.

map_viewer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_above="@id/actionBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <fragment 
                   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                   android:id="@+id/map"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   map:uiRotateGestures="false"               
                   class="com.glympsefunctionalitydemo.maps.Map"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                   android:id="@+id/footer_map"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                   <include layout="@layout/footer/>"
            </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

footer.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <RelativeLayout 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:background="@null">

           <ImageButton 
                  android:id="@+id/actionBtn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@null"
              android:src="@drawable/btn_actions"/>
           <ImageButton
                  android:id="@+id/mapBtn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/footer_horizontal_margin"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@null"
              android:src="@drawable/btn_map"/>
           <ImageButton 
                  android:id="@+id/mapBtn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/footer_horizontal_margin"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@null"
              android:src="@drawable/btn_settings"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

The map takes all the space, the footer overlayed the map. But i just want the map to take the space left when showing the footer. How can i get it working.

[image]

Comment: Sorry keshav, i post the code. Thanks!

Comment: Why  are you using FrameLayout? Is it necessary ?

Comment: Although changing to use another layout(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout), it's still not working

Comment: try my answer's layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for map_viewer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.glympsefunctionalitydemo.maps.Map"
        map:uiRotateGestures="false" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer" >
    </include>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replying! But it's still not working, the map fragment filled all the parent screen height when running on real device.

Comment: But its fine here. Try to put the include layout code inside the map_viewer.xml

Comment: Yes, it works fine when we put the footer code into the map_viewer.xml! But the problem comes out when using <include /> tag, maybe the system doesnt know about the included layout when rendering.